# Regex pattern to match positive and negative number values in a String

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, negative-number

I have pattern/matcher lines that transform input Strings like this:

```
1 3 Hi [2 1 4]
```

into an Array like this:

```
[0] => "1"
[1] => "3"
[2] => "Hi"
[3] => "2 1 4"
```

That's the code:

```
String input = sc.nextLine();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[)[^\\]]+|\\w+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
List<String> cIn = new ArrayList<String>();
while(m.find()) cIn.add(m.group());
```

Now I realised that sometimes I could get some negative values, inputs like `4 2 -1 2`. Since the input is a String, i can't really use any regular expression to get that negative value.

Below in the code, I use

```
Integer.parseInt(cIn.get(0));
```

to transform that string value into the Integer, that is actually what I need.

Could you figure a way that allows me to keep together the `-` char and the number char? Then I would just check if there's the `-` char to transform the number and multiply it by `-1`. (If there's a better way I'd be glad to hear).

As usual, excuse me for my English.

Comment: +1, and no need to apologize for your English. It's quite good. :-)

Comment: Could you just split on spaces and parse normally? Why use a regex?

Comment: @DaveNewton He wants to capture sequences in `[]` as a token, even if they include whitespace.  (But I'm also fond of the regex-less approach!)

Comment: @cheeken I meant after the group is captured. Personally this looks more like a job for an actual parser than regex, although if this is as complex as things get, maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question - you should really provide a plain description of the full effect of what you're trying to match with this regular expression, as well as perhaps some edge cases which should not match.

Comment: @DaveNewton could be, but I'm just learning Java and I never had to use regex before, so I wanted to give it a try. Performance here isn't really important. Thanks! :)

Comment: @afontcu It's not just a matter of performance, it's a matter of suitability and maintainability. Like I said, if it's never more complicated than this, it's probably fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You absolutely can use a regular expression to capture negative numbers, but it depends on what you're trying to weed out.

```
"(?<=\\[)[^\\]]+|[-\\w]+"
```

The simplest way is to simply add '-' to the group of recognized word characters.  However, this will also result in weird formations like '9-9' being legal.  Considering you already match tokens like '9_9', I'm not sure that's a problem for you.  I'd probably just add another alternation to the end of this regex:

```
"(?<=\\[)[^\\]]+|\\w+|-?\\d+"
```

Which allows an optional '-' character followed by at least one digit.  Or, a negative number.  This is fairly robust - you're literally just defining an additional type of match (a very specific one), but every time you find a new case, you really shouldn't just keep adding '|...' to the end of your regex.  It's about the least efficient way to do what you're doing.  It seems, in your situation, that this isn't really a problem, but you should think about this as your use case expands.

Comment: Hm, thats easier than i thought. I tried to go around and include the "-" char after \\w+ (\\w+\\-) but that didn't work well. 

I just thought that, since I'm getting a String, I could not evaluate the number as positive or negative.
I think I just have to give it more tries before asking on the internet, lesson learned. 

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way: `(?<=\\[)[^\\]]+|-?\\w+`.

The `-?` regex means that you can have a `-` or not before the word (`\\w+`) but if you need only digits then use `\\d+` and `\\w+`.

Here is the test i wrote:

```
@Test
public void regex() {

    String input = "-1 3 Hi [2 1 4]";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[)[^\\]]+|-?\\w+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    List<String> cIn = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find())
        cIn.add(m.group());

    System.out.println(cIn);

}
```

It yields `[-1, 3, Hi, 2 1 4]` as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an optional `-` in your regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[)[^\\]]+|-?\\w+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Very fancy regular expression, but what about something with fewer tricks that captures what you are trying to do?

```
(?:\[(?:\s*[-]?\d+\s*)*\]|(?:[-]?\d+|\w+))
```